# sql error about where and group by

Tags: sql

I got a question from http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT_Quiz#quiz0, the 4th one. I chose the second option, but it turned out the fifth option is the right answer. I don't know why this sql sentence is wrong. Can anyone tell me the reason? Thank you in advance.

the sql sentence is shown below:

```
SELECT region, SUM(area)
FROM bbc 
WHERE SUM(area) > 15000000 
GROUP BY region
```

why the answer to this problem is "No result due to invalid use of the WHERE function"?

Comment: You cannot put aggregation functions (such as `sum()`) in the `where` clause.  They belong in the `having` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SUM(area) in WHERE clause.

For that to be valid you had to use HAVING after the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT region, SUM(area) FROM bbc GROUP BY region HAVING SUM(area) > 15000000;
```

Comment: In what criteria do we use HAVING instead of WHERE?

Comment: When you use Aggregate functions like SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX.. In those cases you can't use them on WHERE, but on HAVING

Answer (score 1):

To understand why take a look at a logical query processing order which roughly looks like

1. FROM
2. **WHERE**
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

`WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY` therefore you can't use aggregate functions directly in it. That what the `HAVING` clause is for.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` operates on non-aggregated data, i.e. *before* `GROUP BY`. `HAVING` is meant to be used on aggregated data i.e. *after* `GROUP BY`.